# can subclass of another subclass inherit method from base class in c#

Tags: c#

Say Class A is the base class and then you have class B subclass of A (class B : A).  Then you have class C : B.

Question is if you have a method in class A, can class C use that method?

Comment: Here is a small example to go along with everyone's answers: http://ideone.com/E0xVzZ

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can, if it is declared `public` or `protected`. but not `private`.

Thanks to @DavidL.. I forgot to mention the special case of `internal`.

From C# Manual that comes with Visual Studio (2012 edition here)::

- •    Inheritance is transitive. If C is derived from B, and B is derived
  from A, then C inherits the members declared in B as well as the
  members declared in A. • A derived class extends its direct base
  class. A derived class can add new members to those it inherits, but
  it cannot remove the definition of an inherited member. •    Instance
  constructors, destructors, and static constructors are not inherited,
  but all other members are, regardless of their declared accessibility
  (§3.5). However, depending on their declared accessibility, inherited
  members might not be accessible in a derived class. •    A derived class
  can hide (§3.7.1.2) inherited members by declaring new members with
  the same name or signature. Note however that hiding an inherited
  member does not remove that member—it merely makes that member
  inaccessible directly through the derived class. •   An instance of a
  class contains a set of all instance fields declared in the class and
  its base classes, and an implicit conversion (§6.1.6) exists from a
  derived class type to any of its base class types. Thus, a reference
  to an instance of some derived class can be treated as a reference to
  an instance of any of its base classes. •    A class can declare virtual
  methods, properties, and indexers, and derived classes can override
  the implementation of these function members. This enables classes to
  exhibit polymorphic behavior wherein the actions performed by a
  function member invocation varies depending on the run-time type of
  the instance through which that function member is invoked.

Also this is a new hiding feature, if I am right, in C# 5.0:

A nested type may hide (§3.7.1) a base member. The new modifier is permitted on nested type declarations so that hiding can be expressed explicitly. The example

```
using System;

class Base
{
    public static void M() {
        Console.WriteLine("Base.M");
    }
}
class Derived: Base 
{
    new public class M 
    {
        public static void F() {
            Console.WriteLine("Derived.M.F");
        }
    }
}
class Test 
{
    static void Main() {
        Derived.M.F();
    }
}
```

shows a nested class M that hides the method M defined in Base.

Comment: Don't forget about special cases where internal is also applicable :)

Comment: Method hiding isn't new in 5.0; it's been around since (I believe) 1.0, and if not then, then in 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

- When the method in class A is private: no
- When the method in class A is protected: yes
- When the method in class A is public: yes
- When the method in class A is public or protected and virtual, class C can override that method.

Comment: It might also be prudent to note that if the method is virtual then Class B could prevent Class C from overriding the method by marking it as `sealed`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when you inherit from a class you get all of it's methods, including all those it inherited from others.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    protected int protectedId { get; set; }
    private int privateId;
}

public class B : A
{
}

public class C : B
{
    public C()
    {
        int temp = Id; // works
        int temp1 = protectedId; // works
        int temp2 = privateId; // does NOT work
    }
}
```

and in some other class;

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
    C c = new C();
    int i = c.Id; // works
    int j = c.protectedId; // does NOT work
    int k = c.privateId; // does NOT work
}
```